# Raspberry pi 4B wifi problem

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi

For some time my raspberry pi was not able to connect to my home wifi. It's been working well for quite some time, and the only thing that could have affected it was system updates. It has raspberry pi OS. I've checked SSID and password and confirmed they are correct.
Output of ip a:

```
-- snip --
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:0f:3d:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Output of sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Arrakis'
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Arrakis'
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'Arrakis'
```

Same things keep repeating.
Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`.

Comment: I do not have such file present.

Comment: After reinstalling OS problem persisted. Unplugging HDMI worked. https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/121